# Django: why a keyerror instead of a validation error?

Tags: django, django-forms

why comes a keyerror instead of a validation error when one field is empty? The fields should be `required=True` by default

```
class form(forms.ModelForm):
    adminAccount = forms.CharField()
    adminPassword = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def userCheck(self, user, password):
        # do something

    def clean(self):
        self.userCheck(self.cleaned_data['adminAccount'], 
                       self.cleaned_data['adminPassword'])
```

Comment: maybe you should also put `try` and `except`, and you didn't also return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your code that is raising the `KeyError` here:

```
self.userCheck(self.cleaned_data['adminAccount'],
               self.cleaned_data['adminPassword'])
```

Because you're trying to access `self.cleaned_data[field]` when field was not posted.

The [documentation provides an example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) that explains how to validate data that depends on more than one field. According to the examples you should do something like:

```
cleaned_data = super(form, self).clean()
adminAccount = cleaned_data.get('adminAccount')
adminPassword = cleaned_data.get('adminPassword')

if adminAccount and adminPassword:
    # proceed with your validation

return cleaned_data
```

Also, remember that `Form.clean()` must return the cleaned_data dict.

Comment: Yes, it is. But shouldn't 'clean(self)' proove at first if 'adminAccount' is valid?

Comment: Django runs the whole [validation machinery as described in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/) on the form to collect all errors. It doesn't stop at `ValidationError`, it just collects an error so you can access it through `form.errors`. So your `clean()` method will be called regardless of the result of single fields validation.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So i just put it in an if-statement. That should work.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example from the docs, hope this helps.

Comment: i get still an keyerror by using the if-statement: 'if self.cleaned_data['adminAccount'] and self.cleaned_data['adminPassword']:'

Comment: Yes, because that tries to access the dict with a key that does not exist. Look at the example in my (updated) answer. It uses `cleaned_data.get()` which doesn't raise when a key does not exist, but returns `None` instead.