# Why does Django throw a KeyError on this form validation?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Here's the code:

```
...

class Meta:
    model = Card

def clean_video_url(self):
    video_url = self.cleaned_data['video_url']
    if video_url != '' and len(video_url) != YOUTUBE_VIDEO_URL_LENGTH:
        pos = string.find(video_url, YOUTUBE_VIDEO_URL_IDENTIFIER)
        identifier_length = len(YOUTUBE_VIDEO_URL_IDENTIFIER)
        if pos == -1:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('youtube-url-not-valid'))
        video_url = video_url[pos+identifier_length:pos+identifier_length+YOUTUBE_VIDEO_URL_LENGTH]
    return video_url

...

def clean(self):
    video_url = self.cleaned_data['video_url']
    field1 = self.cleaned_data['field1']
    if video_url == '' and field1 == '':
        raise forms.ValidationError(_('must-fill-video-url-or-front'))
    return self.cleaned_data
```

The most disturbing thing is that it works (submits and persists in the database) in almost all situations. It doesn't work when I write dummy text like 'aeuchah' in the **video_url field**, but instead it throws:

```
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'video_url'
```

I re-read my clean_video_url method and went to see what the variables were with a debug tool like pdb.set_trace, but I can't find the problem.

**UPDATE**: **As Marius Grigaitis and Davide R. said, the clean method is called after all the individual field methods are done. clean_video_url raised a ValidationError and returned nothing, so the clean method found nothing to work with and raised a KeyError.**

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: I answered to this exact same question earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382914/

Comment: You were right, that was indeed the problem. I understand how form validation works better now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always check that key exists in `cleaned_data` before using it in `clean()` method. You're not guaranteed that value is present in cleaned_data array if previous validations has not passed.

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

> By the time the form’s `clean()` method is called, all the individual field clean methods will have been run (the previous two sections), so self.cleaned_data will be populated with any data that has survived so far. So you also need to remember to allow for the fact that the fields you are wanting to validate might not have survived the initial individual field checks.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, that solved my persisting problem. I inspected clean_video_url but not the clean method.